# How can I compile a program and update an program already installed

Tags: apt, compiling, vsftpd

So I have vsftpd 2.3.5 installed (using apt-get) and I want to install [vsftpd-ext](http://vsftpd.devnet.ru/eng/).
But I have to compile it my self and install.

How can I install it so that it updates the version installed by apt-get
and I still can run, for example, service vsftpd start

As I did it now the program is just installed "side by side" and not updated the already installed version. (Following this guide: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/vsftpd-setup/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you have two conflicting pieces of software installed; 'vsftp' and 'vsftp-ext'.

First you need to remove the version installed by apt-get. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove vsftpd
```

This will remove the version of vsftpd installed by apt-get. Once you've done that, it's probably a good idea to recompile 'vsftpd-ext', just to make sure everything is setup properly. Just follow that guide again, and everything should be fine.

Comment: If I run service vsftpd I get "vsftpd: unrecognized service"

Comment: Try 'service vsftpd-ext' instead.

Comment: I get the same error: vsftpd-ext: unrecognized service